# wordpress . com plugins?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am working on a app where I need to share the posts of a WordPress, it is not WP dot org, it is WP dot com, I need to install some plugin like the JSON API plugin, but I am unable to see the plugin link in the menu. I am the creator of this WP, I was reading about the Super Admin all of that, but I am the Super Admin.

[image]

so what should I do here ? or what do you recommend me to do in order to share the posts of the WP blog in my app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [The difference between WordPress.com, WordPress, and WordPress.org » en.wordpress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/)

Basically, you can't install plugins at .COM (as well as do many other things, like use your own themes, etc).

You can do anything you want when you self-host Wordpress, i.e. download and install from .ORG.

Take a look at [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting » wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/hosting/) and [WordPress » Requirements » wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)

Comment: hey thank you, then, just one more question: If I don't want to use anything regarding wordpress.org, can I get the posts from my wordpress.com in order to post it in my app ?

Comment: You should be able to pull the with plain RSS.

Comment: is there any tutorial or something ?